# Best way to provide access control on datastore entities with parent relationship

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Suppose I have Three kind of entities- Users,Posts,Comments.
Every Post has a parent User and every comment has a parent Post i.e.
User->Post->comment.

**My APIs looks like below:**

key here is the websafe key of entity

GET /user/{key} - get user info

POST /user/{key}/post/ - create post

GET /post/{key} - get post

POST /post/{key}/comment/ - create comment

GET /comment/{key}

**Questions :**

1. Problem here is that if user1 knows the key of user2 then user1 can
   access the data of user2.
2. I read about multi-tenancy in datastore but got confused whether it
   is suitable for this type of datastore design or not. Because I have
   more than 100 users and it may increase.
3. Should I need to manually handle this? If yes then what will be the
   best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good, restful API design (although the popular convention is to pluralize collections - `/users/{key}`, `/posts/{key}/comments`, etc).

You should handle authorization checks explicitly. The implementation of `GET /users/{key}` should check if the caller has rights to view that object and return either HTTP 401 or 403. Presumably the caller is determined by some sort of authentication header.

You are probably considering an alternative like `GET /myuser` or `GET /myposts`. Sometimes this can be useful but it's best to avoid this sort of thing if possible - it violates the spirit of REST and cache-ability of GET. Also, it's best to have URLs that work not only for the specific user, but also allow any superuser to perform the same action on behalf of the user. These URLs need to work on explicit objects.

Re: Multitenancy. I would strongly advise avoiding it. I don't think it's particularly useful, and it will be especially confusing if you're new to GAE. Just model the data you need - if posts are associated with a user, store that information in the post and use it to perform authorization checks or filtering.

Comment: thanks for replying @stickfigure . Can you please tell me what are the reasons for avoiding multitenancy? when one should use multitenancy?